# Publishing big binary files stops at Committing Deployment phase and fails

Tags: publishing, web8.5

I published a page, but publishing stops in Committing Deployment phase for log time(more than 30 minutes) and fails. The page publishes many binary files(transport package is more than 500mb).

Publishing other pages which use same template and publish smaller amount of binary files succeeds, so I guess published file size is problem.

Error message of publishing queue is following.
[image]

There is no error log in Content Deployer's log file.

Content Deployer's maximun size permitted for upload size is 10GB(big enough), which is set in application.properties file.

What is possible cause of this error?

**Update**

I modified deployer log level to DEBUG, then following log was output.

> 2019-01-23 21:48:10,568 WARN  TridionTransactionalExecutableStep -
>   Rollback transaction due to error. ExecutionId: tcm:0-412299-66560
>   error: Attempting to deploy a binary 960461 to a location where a
>   different binary is already stored Existing binary: 453791:

Problem was that a binary file had already been published to a directory, but tried to publish another Multimedia component which has same binary file name to the same directory.

I remember this log was ERROR level at old version, but on Web8.5, it seems to be WARN level.

Comment: Could be due to disk space or some other constraints in the target system. I'd set the deployer log to DEBUG and try it.